# Getting problems with table in struts to convert its data to a pdf format

Tags: java, pdf, struts-1

i have an application in which i have a table and that table is converting its data to a pdf file it is in sturts and it is working fine.But i have to add this capability to another application which also have  a table with data from the database.i am posting my working code and also the piece of code where i want to add this capability....
this is the page from where i am exporting the data to a pdf file.i have implemented this in my table but when i click on the table

```
    <display:table class="tableData context-menu-one" name="sessionScope.DetailsFormBean.listOfUser" requestURI="/search.do" id="tableData" pagesize="10" style="overflow-x: scroll" export="true">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="font-size: 14px;" >
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column  title="Favourites"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="call_type" title="CALL_TYPE"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="a_no" title="A_NO"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="b_no" title="B_NO"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="call_duration" title="CALL_DURATION"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="start_day" title="START_DAY"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="end_day" title="END_DAY"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="a_home_circle" title="A_HOME_CIRCLE"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="a_rome_circle" title="A_ROME_CIRCLE"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="a_imei" title="A_IMEI"/></th>
                            <th  align="left"> <display:column property="a_imsi" title="A_IMSI"/></th>

                            <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ActorDetails.xls"/>
                            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="ActorDetails.pdf"/>
                            <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
                        </display:table> 




  <action input="/"  name="DetailsFormBean"  path="/search" scope="session" type="com.homeland.action.HomeLandPersonalAction" parameter="search">
        <forward name="found" path="/searchpage.jsp"/>
    </action>
```

the table dissapears  when i click on the export to pdf options....somebody please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting as pdf,csv & xml is from `struts-displaytag` properties. You have to use displaytag in your JSP page and then use the list `actorList`.

**It doesn't depend on Database**. Once the list gets the values (either from DB or other ways-hard coded too), you can display it in your JSP using `displaytag` property. And it will show the option of exporting, provided you set it to true.

This would looks like the same as in your question.

```
<display:table id="data" name="sessionScope.UserForm.actorList" requestURI="/userAction.do" pagesize="10" export="true">
        <display:column property="tvShow" title="TV Show" sortable="true" media="html" group="1" />
        <display:column property="userName" title="User Name" sortable="true" />
        <display:column property="emailId" title="Email Id" sortable="true" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ActorDetails.xls"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="ActorDetails.pdf"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
    </display:table>
```

Comment: its working for me as i posted the code already but i need that function in my table

Comment: thank you for youe help its working now..can you explain one thing what is that <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="ActorDetails.xls"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="ActorDetails.pdf"/>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" /> things i can not understand that if this things you can explain i will solve it properly

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer. Please go through http://www.displaytag.org/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html

Comment: i have a problem here i have implemented this things in my table but my xport to pdf option is not working properly when i click on that option the table vanishes..i am posting my code